# Is it really safe to use vanitygen to generate your unique bitcoin address?

Tags: wallet-security, vanitygen

I've been wondering if using vanitygen to create your own bitcoin address with a unique prefix, is safe from being compromise by others? I'm currently using a shared wallet address from a trusted website and I'm targeting now to create my own bitcoin address using vanitygen. Can someone enlighten me? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Using vanitygen you might think that you would be able to find the private key for a given address. In practice, this is considered impossible. Given that the difficulty increases exponentially the longer your vanity is, so does the average time required to find that vanity. The example table below shows how an increasingly complex vanity affects the difficulty and average time required to find a match only for that vanity, let alone the full address, for a machine capable of looking through 1 million keys per second."

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen#Use_of_vanitygen_to_try_to_attack_addresses

vanity  difficulty  average time

1B  22  < 1s

1Bi 1,330   < 1s

1Bit    77,178  < 1s

1Bitc   4,476,342 (4.48E+6) < 10s

1Bitco  259,627,881 (2.6E+8)    3 minutes

1Bitcoi 15,058,417,127 (1.506E+10)  3 hours

1Bitcoin    8.7339E+11  1 week

1BitcoinE   5.0657E+13  1 year

1BitcoinEa  2.9381E+15  60 years

1BitcoinEat 1.7041E+17  3,500 years

1BitcoinEate    9.8837E+18  200,000 years

1BitcoinEater   5.7325E+20  11,700,000 years

1BitcoinEaterAddressDontSend    1.6209E+47  3.3E+33 or 3.3 decillion years

Comment: On the other hand: key reuse is bad for anonymity for yourself and others as well as reduces your security. Depending on how you generate the vanity address, you're also adding steps that can fail to the process of creating a private key and therefore possibly increase the chances of a MITM or other hacker gaining access to your key. All in all definitely less safe.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.